# Find a maximal subgraph on a tree with conditions

Tags: graphs, trees, graph-traversal

Given a tree, find a path on which every vertex has at most 4 leaves (can have 0 as well) and is the "biggest" (has the maximum amount of vertices possible - including the leaves).
Time complexity: $O(n)$.

I'm getting nowhere with this problem. I have tried BFS/DFS (seemed like such an obvious method), but even if I could modify them correctly, their time complexity is $O(|V|+|E|)$.

Any hint, thought is appreciated.

***edit:*** so now I get that BFS/DFS is valid for this problem, but I'm still having difficulties with figuring out the algorithm itself. Help please.

Comment: Hint: how many vertices and edges does a tree have? Specifically, what is the relationship between the two?

Comment: Well, a tree has exactly $n-1$ edges (given that the tree is connected) and there is no cycle in them. Sorry, but I don't get how does this help me.

Comment: Right, so you have that $n > m$, which implies that $O(n + m) = O(n)$.

Comment: Oh my... Never thought about this. Thank you. So, BFS/DFS is a valid option on trees.

Comment: So... will one of you provide an answer, or do we close/delete this? (cc @Juho)

Comment: I'm working on the modification of BFS, but if @Juho puts this into an answer, I would be happy to accept it.

Comment: What is your more specific problem now?

Comment: Simple DFS/BFS doesn't seem to work and I don't know how to modify them to solve my problem.

Comment: What's your best try so far? Where does it fail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea is that if you have a vertex having more than 4 leaves in the tree you could never take it in your final path. The steps of the Algorithm is as follows:

1. Delete the vertices having more than 4 leaves and the edges incident on them.
2. By deleting those vertices and edges you'll get a forest having trees say T1,...,Tk.
3. Then find simply the biggest path in each of those trees.
4. Take the maximum over all of those paths.

In 1st step you can keep a counter for all the vertices. Add one to the counters of the neighbors of each leaf. Delete the vertices having counter value > 4. So, it takes O(n) time.

Now in 3rd step finding a biggest path in a tree is straightforward using DFS.

Thus in total it takes O(n) time.